# Android issue with view image on ImageView

Tags: java, android

I am try to get image from my server using `bitmap`. It's work fine, image hight resolution, but i see it in the middle of my imageView. Image view has full container width.
There code of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/android_bg" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/registration_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Bentornato"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/home_logo"


        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So my imageView has id home_logo and has width match_parent. 
What can i do wrong?
[image]

Comment: You can also set the background of the imageview to black instead of scaling it to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Use this tag in your ImageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Follow this details tutorial

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2

[image]

Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by setting image as background of `imageview`

```
     imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```